# Create several bitmaps from a large bitmap using paths or rects

Tags: android, path, bitmap, clip, rect

So I have a bitmap.. Now I want to create 5 smaller bitmaps from specific regions of the original bitmap.

Is it possible to do this with paths or rects?

for instance : `newBitmap = OriginalBitmap.copyFromArea(Path data | rect)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) static method form the `Bitmap` class.

For example, if you have a 20x25 image (`originalBitmap`) and want a 5x6 slice (`newSlice`) at the bottom right corner, then you can do the following:

```
Bitmap newSlice = Bitmap.createBitmap (originalBitmap, 15, 19, 5, 6);
```